# Scrollbars visible, can't scroll

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have the following HTML (demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/49Phn/) which has an inner DIV with an ID of `tabs`:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="tabs">
            <div id="j1">
                <div class="letter">
                    <p>Section 1</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="j2">
                <div class="letter">
                    <p>Section 2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="j3">
                <div class="letter">
                    <p>Section 3</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="j4">
                <div class="letter">
                    <p>Section 4</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="popup-container">
        <div id="popup">
            <div id="pheader">
                <a id="close-popup"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS (sorry it's so long):

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

@font-face {
    font-family: PhinsterFine;
    src: url('../fonts/PhinsterFine.ttf');
}

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    text-shadow: none;
    color: black;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.hub ui-page, .hub .ui-body-c,
.ui-overlay-c ui-page, .ui-overlay-c .ui-body-c,
.ui-mobile-viewport ui-page, .ui-overlay-c .ui-body-c {
    z-index: -2 !important;
}

/*----------------------------------- Crimson Tide - non-jQuery styles ------------------------------------*/

.hub #content {
    z-index: -1;
}

.hub #header, .hub #content, .hub #popup-container {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    /* font-variant : small-caps; */
    position: absolute;
}

.hub #header {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    top: 0;
    background: #eee no-repeat 50% / 130px;
}

.hub #content {
    top: 40px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    bottom: 45px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
}

.hub #popup-container {
    opacity: .95;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.hub #popup-container #popup {
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

.hub #popup-container #popup #header {
    position: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;

    background: #eeeeee; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%, #333333 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#eeeeee), color-stop(100%,#333333)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#333333 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#333333 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#333333 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #eeeeee 0%,#333333 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#333333',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 7px;

    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
}

.hub #content #tabs {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
    background: #f00;
    text-align: center;
}

.hub #content #tabs > div {
    padding: 5px 20px 40px 20px;
    float: left;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hub #content #tabs :active > div {
    background: #fff;
}

.letter {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 80px #A0A0A0;
    margin: 16px auto 0;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 250px;
    height: 70%;
}

.letter:before, .letter:after {
    content: "";
    height: 98%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.letter:before {
    background: #baffc4;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    left: -5px;
    top: 4px;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-1.5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-1.5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-1.5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-1.5deg);
    transform: rotate(-1.5deg);
}

.letter:after {
    background: #80FF93;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    right: -3px;
    top: 1px;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(1.4deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(1.4deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(1.4deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(1.4deg);
    transform: rotate(1.4deg);
}

.count {
    font-family: helvetica, san-serif;
    font-size: .7em;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 60%;
    top: 30%;
    background: #baffc4;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

.hub #content #tabs div h2 {
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

My content container contains four boxes, which, if you shrink the window height - you'll see they're hidden which is the desired behaviour.

However, I need this container div to scroll - and it shows the scroll bar (on Windows) - which looks round about the correct height, but isn't actually scrolling. Any idea?

The reason it's bound to the screen edges is because it's a mobile app designed to run on multiple screen sizes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed it. I removed the following few lines:

```
.hub ui-page, .hub .ui-body-c,
.ui-overlay-c ui-page, .ui-overlay-c .ui-body-c,
.ui-mobile-viewport ui-page, .ui-overlay-c .ui-body-c {
    z-index: -2;
}
```

And changed:

```
.hub #content {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

To:

```
.hub #content {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I don't think it liked the minus z-indexes, hazard a guess.

Answer (score 3):

I removed the OverFlow: auto; and then I was able to scroll on your page. There are something that makes it stuck when you add this function.

```
.hub #content {
    top: 40px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    bottom: 45px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/49Phn/2/)

But atm I cant really tell you why it stuck when you use overflow. It should work

Edited: Try Check your Css from:

```
.hub #header, .hub #content, .hub #popup-container {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    /* font-variant : small-caps; */
    position: absolute;
}
```

To

```
.hub #header, .hub #content, .hub #popup-container {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    /* font-variant : small-caps; */
    position: fixed;
}
```

That fixed the scroll problem for me

Comment: Yeah I also found that - but if you then look at my inner div, it doesn't follow the rules of `bottom: 45px`.

Comment: Updated with a Posible solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're right about the z-index, but it's not only negative values that cause this.

I just came across the same problem (thanks for pointing me in the right direction).

In my case, I had no z-index set on the div at all. Setting a **positive** z-index fixed it for me.